# View Cookie information on Android

Tags: android, cookies

I am wondering if it is possible to view cookies information Android for all apps. I know that we do not have to log in for each app every time, and there should be some place to store the cookie information.

I am not a developer myself, and therefore I would prefer that if there is some Android app to help me achieve that.

Comment: There are not called cookies in Android. There are called `SharedPreferences`.  Due to security limitations (an app hijacking your login info from other apps) it's not possible to access other apps' shared preferences, unless your device is rooted and the user has granted root permission to your app.

Comment: The phone is rooted. I download some app, and I am monitoring its interaction with my phone and network. I am the owner of the phone. Do you know what the next is to do? Thanks. You can put in the answer section.

Comment: If the phone is rooted, try using [Preferences Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.preferencesmanager&hl=en).

Comment: This question is also more suited for the [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!